# What is the fastest way to solve this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, dc

Since V+ and V- are both @ 0 volts I thought I could combine these resistors in series and parallel, but that gave me the wrong answer. (The right answer is Vout = -4IR)

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way, I think, is just to redraw the darned thing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSFoiq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I show the virtual ground node on the bottom, lower left side there. That's the \$V_-\$ input to the opamp. But you know that there's a current, \$I\$, that must be driven through the first \$R\$ in your schematic (\$R_1\$ in mine.) So \$V_1=I R\$. Clearly, \$V_1\$ also means that there is an added \$I\$ coming in from \$R_2\$; which joins with the other \$I\$ to make for \$2I\$, now. This larger current must flow through \$R_3\$. When it does, it develops a voltage across \$R_3\$ that is equal to \$V_2=2I\cdot R_3+V_1=2IR\$. \$V_2\$ now causes a current in \$R_4\$, which is equal to \$2I\$. This adds to the current in \$R_3\$ to make a total current of \$4I\$ in \$R_5\$. This means that \$V_{OUT}=4I R_5 + V_2=4IR\$.

I think that's the simplest way to picture the answer.

---

Bear in mind that your output will have to slew, negatively, for a positive current into the \$V_-\$ node. So the above discussion is entirely about the magnitude, and not the sign, of \$V_{OUT}\$. (Note added per ThePhoton's comment here. Thanks!)

---

A completely different approach using Thevenin would be to, let's say, start at the output end and work backwards. I'll use my resistor numbering from above (since you didn't number yours.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUD0Hv.png)</sup>

Starting at the output, we have the Thevenin of the obvious first divider:

$$\begin{align*}
R_{TH}&=\frac{R_4\cdot R_5}{R_4+R_5}\\\\
V_{TH}&=V_{OUT}\cdot\frac{R_4}{R_4+R_5}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

\$V_{TH}\$'s series \$R_{TH}\$ impedance is also in series with \$R_3\$, so: \$R^{'}_{TH}=R_3+R_{TH}\$. This modified Thevenin output resistance now forms a divider with \$R_2\$. So:

$$\begin{align*}
R^{''}_{TH}&=\frac{R^{'}_{TH}\cdot R_2}{R^{'}_{TH}+ R_2}\\\\
V^{''}_{TH}&=V_{TH}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R^{'}_{TH}+ R_2}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

\$V^{''}_{TH}\$'s series \$R^{''}_{TH}\$ impedance is also in series with \$R_1\$, so: \$R^{'''}_{TH}=R_1+R^{''}_{TH}\$.

That's about it. The sum of the currents into the \$V_-\$ node must equal zero. So:

$$I + \frac{V^{''}_{TH} - 0\:\textrm{V}}{R^{'''}_{TH}}=0$$

Just given the above, alone, you can then solve for \$V_{OUT}\$. This works out to:

$$\begin{align*}
\textrm{setting }R_X&=R_3+R_5+\frac{R_3\cdot R_5}{R_4}\textrm{, then:}\\\\
V_{OUT}&=-I\cdot\left[R_X\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)+R_1\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_5}{R_4}\right)\right]\\\\
&=-I\cdot\left[\left(R_3+R_5+\frac{R_3\cdot R_5}{R_4}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)+R_1\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_5}{R_4}\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

If you plug in \$R_1=R_2=R_4=R\$ and \$R_3=R_5=\frac{R}{2}\$, then you will get the same \$V_{OUT}=-4IR\$ result.

Comment: @gabson Hopefully, that approach works for you, too. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be -4IR? Or am I not really awake yet?

Comment: @ThePhoton No, you are awake. I was merely trying to provide the fastest way to reach the answer sought by the OP. I'll add magnitude bars, or something.